# Office.js Calendar Date handling

Tags: javascript, outlook, ms-office, office365-apps

I'm working on an extension for office365, and encountered this behavior:

Currently it looks like that Office's calendar app is handling dates incorrectly. Take a look at this example:

```js
  window.Office.initialize = function () {
    window.Office.context.mailbox.item.start.getAsync(function (result) {
      window.Office.context.mailbox.item.start.setAsync(result.value);
    });
  };
```

Expected behavior is that this would not change the date, as we set it to the same it already is.

However, this seems to not work like that - date seems to be set in a way that timezone data is discarded and raw hours & minutes are used.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: No question mark. What's the question?

Comment: I'm seeking insight into what am I doing wrong here (because I'm sure I am doing something wrong here).

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the behabior you described is obviously correct behavior per documentation on [Office.context.mailbox.item.start](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.context.mailbox.item.html#start)?

Let me provide you with a couple of quotes ...

"The start property is expressed as a Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) date and time value. You can use the [convertToLocalClientTime](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.context.mailbox.html#convertToLocalClientTime) method to convert the value to the client’s local date and time."

"When you use the Time.setAsync method to set the start time, you should use the [convertToUtcClientTime](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.context.mailbox.html#convertToUtcClientTime) method to convert the local time on the client to UTC for the server."

Bottom line: use the converters for date/time. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, and this makes total sense. However, I don't think that's not the way that Outlook currently works.

In my above example the Date is not being modified, so it is, as we expect, UTC, right? In that case the time should remain the same, and should not change?

Comment: OK, I took a time to create a test project. Let me clarify we work on the same page. 1. Appointment type of the item (edit mode). 2. The date/time of the item is not manipulated and set in UTC format. 3. Test for Outlook for Web (browser version). If all pre-conditions are the same, I don't have any issues with timezone. I also tried to convert to local time add one hour, convert to UTC and set it back. All of this worked as expected. I am able to add my test code if you wish.

Comment: Were you on same TZ that your outlook account is set to? For example:
My outlook account is set to Easter Time TZ, while my browser timezone is Eastern European Time.

Maybe problem could be here? Maybe outlook just gets confused

Comment: I have both system and Outlook timezone set to EST (-5). When I did the initial tests I had no issues with this configuration. I have changed my Outlook to Atlantic (-4) and there are some discrepancy, but never when operated with UTC only. Basically if I use you snippet as is it works properly. When I would try to use convert functions to local time and back, I would have -1 hour difference and appointment would move for 1 hour back. This I observed when Outlook for Web used. Desktop works as expected.